# How to use CholmodSupport in Eigen3 under Ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, eigen, eigen3, suitesparse

I made such a tiny example:

solver.h

```
#pragma once

#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <Eigen/Sparse>
#include <Eigen/CholmodSupport>

typedef Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> SpMat;

class UseCholmodSolver
{
    public:
        UseCholmodSolver() {}
        ~UseCholmodSolver() {}
    private:
        Eigen::CholmodSupernodalLLT<SpMat> cholmod;
};
```

solver.cpp

```
#include "solver.h"
```

main.cpp

```
#include "solver.h"

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Makefile

```
CXXFLAGS=-g -O2 -Wall -DNDEBUG -I./ext/eigen -I/usr/include/suitesparse
CXX=g++

all: t1
clean:
    rm -f *.o main

main.o: main.cpp solver.h
solver.o: solver.cpp solver.h

t1: main.o
    $(CXX) main.o -o main -lcholmod
t2: main.o solver.o
    $(CXX) main.o solver.o -o main -lcholmod
```

When I execute "make t1", everything is fine.
However, when I type "make t2", there are redefinition errors:

```
g++ main.o solver.o -o main -lcholmod
solver.o: In function `int Eigen::internal::cm_start<long>(cholmod_common_struct&)':
/home/xiang/Code/testEigen/./ext/eigen/Eigen/src/CholmodSupport/CholmodSupport.h:177: multiple definition of `int Eigen::internal::cm_start<long>(cholmod_common_struct&)'
main.o:/home/xiang/Code/testEigen/./ext/eigen/Eigen/src/CholmodSupport/CholmodSupport.h:177: first defined here
solver.o: In function `int Eigen::internal::cm_finish<long>(cholmod_common_struct&)':
/home/xiang/Code/testEigen/./ext/eigen/Eigen/src/CholmodSupport/CholmodSupport.h:178: multiple definition of `int Eigen::internal::cm_finish<long>(cholmod_common_struct&)'
main.o:/home/xiang/Code/testEigen/./ext/eigen/Eigen/src/CholmodSupport/CholmodSupport.h:178: first defined here
solver.o: In function `int Eigen::internal::cm_free_factor<long>(cholmod_factor_struct*&, cholmod_common_struct&)':
/home/xiang/Code/testEigen/./ext/eigen/Eigen/src/CholmodSupport/CholmodSupport.h:180: multiple definition of `int Eigen::internal::cm_free_factor<long>(cholmod_factor_struct*&, cholmod_common_struct&)'
main.o:/home/xiang/Code/testEigen/./ext/eigen/Eigen/src/CholmodSupport/CholmodSupport.h:180: first defined here
solver.o: In function `int Eigen::internal::cm_free_dense<long>(cholmod_dense_struct*&, cholmod_common_struct&)':
/home/xiang/Code/testEigen/./ext/eigen/Eigen/src/CholmodSupport/CholmodSupport.h:181: multiple definition of `int Eigen::internal::cm_free_dense<long>(cholmod_dense_struct*&, cholmod_common_struct&)'
main.o:/home/xiang/Code/testEigen/./ext/eigen/Eigen/src/CholmodSupport/CholmodSupport.h:181: first defined here
solver.o: In function `int Eigen::internal::cm_free_sparse<long>(cholmod_sparse_struct*&, cholmod_common_struct&)':
/home/xiang/Code/testEigen/./ext/eigen/Eigen/src/CholmodSupport/CholmodSupport.h:182: multiple definition of `int Eigen::internal::cm_free_sparse<long>(cholmod_sparse_struct*&, cholmod_common_struct&)'
main.o:/home/xiang/Code/testEigen/./ext/eigen/Eigen/src/CholmodSupport/CholmodSupport.h:182: first defined here
solver.o: In function `cholmod_factor_struct* Eigen::internal::cm_analyze<long>(cholmod_sparse_struct&, cholmod_common_struct&)':
/home/xiang/Code/testEigen/./ext/eigen/Eigen/src/CholmodSupport/CholmodSupport.h:184: multiple definition of `cholmod_factor_struct* Eigen::internal::cm_analyze<long>(cholmod_sparse_struct&, cholmod_common_struct&)'
main.o:/home/xiang/Code/testEigen/./ext/eigen/Eigen/src/CholmodSupport/CholmodSupport.h:184: first defined here
solver.o: In function `cholmod_dense_struct* Eigen::internal::cm_solve<long>(int, cholmod_factor_struct&, cholmod_dense_struct&, cholmod_common_struct&)':
/home/xiang/Code/testEigen/./ext/eigen/Eigen/src/CholmodSupport/CholmodSupport.h:187: multiple definition of `cholmod_dense_struct* Eigen::internal::cm_solve<long>(int, cholmod_factor_struct&, cholmod_dense_struct&, cholmod_common_struct&)'
main.o:/home/xiang/Code/testEigen/./ext/eigen/Eigen/src/CholmodSupport/CholmodSupport.h:187: first defined here
solver.o: In function `cholmod_sparse_struct* Eigen::internal::cm_spsolve<long>(int, cholmod_factor_struct&, cholmod_sparse_struct&, cholmod_common_struct&)':
/home/xiang/Code/testEigen/./ext/eigen/Eigen/src/CholmodSupport/CholmodSupport.h:190: multiple definition of `cholmod_sparse_struct* Eigen::internal::cm_spsolve<long>(int, cholmod_factor_struct&, cholmod_sparse_struct&, cholmod_common_struct&)'
main.o:/home/xiang/Code/testEigen/./ext/eigen/Eigen/src/CholmodSupport/CholmodSupport.h:190: first defined here
solver.o: In function `int Eigen::internal::cm_factorize_p<long>(cholmod_sparse_struct*, double*, long*, unsigned long, cholmod_factor_struct*, cholmod_common_struct&)':
/home/xiang/Code/testEigen/./ext/eigen/Eigen/src/CholmodSupport/CholmodSupport.h:195: multiple definition of `int Eigen::internal::cm_factorize_p<long>(cholmod_sparse_struct*, double*, long*, unsigned long, cholmod_factor_struct*, cholmod_common_struct&)'
main.o:/home/xiang/Code/testEigen/./ext/eigen/Eigen/src/CholmodSupport/CholmodSupport.h:195: first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:14: recipe for target 't2' failed
make: *** [t2] Error 1
```

It seems the reason is the "long" type specialized template functions in "CholmodSupport.h". Any idea to fix this problem?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] (including the commands you used to compile).

Comment: @chtz I made a minimal example and edited the question.

Comment: Thanks for the minimal example. This is indeed a problem within Eigen. I'll commit a fix in a moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a problem with CholmodSupport in the devel-branch of Eigen, which I just fixed here:
https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/commits/5ecddbf9fae7f5a4d4e587b8809d9287306885d3

The problem was that some helper functions (used to delegate to appropriate internal cholmod-functions) were not marked `inline` and thus had multiple definitions, when compiled in different compilation units.

For Eigen 3.3 and Eigen 3.2 your minimal example should work fine.